# BigQuery: No matching signature for operator over Github public data

Tags: sql, github, google-bigquery

I am trying to get some statistics from GitHub public data in Google BigQuery.

When I run this query over the sample database, it works fine:

```sql
SELECT lang.name, COUNT(1) commits
FROM `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.sample_commits` c
join `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.languages` l on l.repo_name = c.repo_name,
unnest (l.language) as lang
GROUP BY lang.name
ORDER BY commits DESC
```

But when I change the query to the full commits database:

```sql
SELECT lang.name, COUNT(1) commits
FROM `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.commits` c
join `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.languages` l on l.repo_name = c.repo_name,
unnest (l.language) as lang
GROUP BY lang.name
ORDER BY commits DESC
```

I get this error:

```
No matching signature for operator = for argument types: STRING, ARRAY<STRING>. Supported signature: ANY = ANY at [3:57]
```

Refering to `repo_name` field on `commits` table.
Which is really strange, because the `repo_name` type is `String` in both `commits` and `sample_commits` table.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Below should address your current issue

```
SELECT lang.name, COUNT(1) commits
FROM `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.commits` c
join `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.languages` l on l.repo_name in unnest(c.repo_name),
unnest (l.language) as lang
GROUP BY lang.name
ORDER BY commits DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

`repo_name` is defined as `STRING REPEATED` in the commits table, so you need to work with it like an array.

Comment: What do I need to change in my query for that?

Comment: l.repo_name = ARRAY_TO_STRING(c.repo_name, "") is the approach?